# How do I make "Edit with Vim" open Vim instead of gVim on windows?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

When installing Vim for Windows 10 64-bit, it also installed an "Edit with Vim" context menu option. Annoyingly, this opens the file in gVim.

**How do I change the "Edit with Vim" context menu option to open vim.exe instead of gVim.exe?**

I looked in the registry and couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you expand your question to indicate how you are calling the "Edit with Vim" context menu?   vim.exe is called from the command line.  gvim.exe will start a window.   Could you give more detail on how you plan to work with an example file?

Comment: @StandardEyre It would seem you don't regularly use Windows (lucky you ;)... When you install Vim in Windows: an explorer context menu option is added to File Explorer (ie: when you right-click a file). It reads "Edit with Vim" for a single file. When more than 1 file is selected, there are 3 options: 1) Edit with multiple Vims, 2) Edit with single Vim, and 3) Diff with Vim. See [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_Vim_to_MS-Windows_File_Explorer_Menu).

Comment: @Roflo  Yes, I do not use Windows that often.  I *do* understand the context menu option. :-)   What I don't understand is the Original Poster's need to change the context menu default settings. I'm seeking clarification on the reason why the  "Edit with Vim" context menu option defaults need to change (from gvim.exe to vim.exe).

Comment: I want to use vim over gvim.

Comment: Which version of windows? Based on my experience, at least some of the registry hacks changed from 7 to 8.

Comment: Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: I just checked my registry (also W10 64-bit) and I do have entries in `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}]` (from the [same link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_Vim_to_MS-Windows_File_Explorer_Menu) in my previous comment). Are you sure you don't have such an entry?

Comment: I would've never thought to look in there. I have it and the data is "Vim Shell Extension," but points to this dll `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\gvimext.dll` how do I make it open vim.exe instead?

Comment: A bit of guesswork here, but the second section in the link I provided has an _alternate method_; perhaps that one works for you?

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: I never want to use vim on windows (I could never get the colours quite right, and the screen refresh was slower) so i just copied gvim as vim (and turn off the menus etc so it look almost the same).

Answer (score 7):

I did this by changing the registry key in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vim\Gvim]`

"Edit with Vim" opens gVim:

```
path=C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe
```

"Edit with Vim" opens Vim:

```
path=C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\vim.exe
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks.